# Bitnami Mariadb docker swarm

Tags: mariadb, docker-swarm, bitnami

i deployed docker swarm stack with bitnami-docker-mariadb, with master and slave configuration. My problem is that i can't log on slave db (which is on second server), the message is: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
Does anyone know reason of this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to salve you need to give value to these environment variables

```
      - MARIADB_REPLICATION_MODE=slave
      - MARIADB_REPLICATION_USER=repl_user
      - MARIADB_REPLICATION_PASSWORD=repl_password
      - MARIADB_MASTER_HOST=mariadb-master
      - MARIADB_MASTER_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MARIADB_MASTER_ROOT_PASSWORD=master_root_password
```